# Installing python 2 deb packages locally in a single project

Tags: package-management, 20.04, deb, python-2.7

I am struggling with cutting off python 2 functionalities from ubuntu 20. I have a project that porting to python 3 may take a lot of time so i have to use ubuntu 18 packages to satisfy its module imports/dependencies. Unfortunately installing those packages with `apt install ./old-deb-package.deb` isn't an option because it wants to downgrade or remove some already installed packages.

Is there a way to install or attach somehow those packages locally to one project only so they would be a part of it, not part of the whole system?

I tried to do it brute force just unpacking .debs to a single directory inside the project and adding entries to import path variable alongside with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it still is missing some internal modules like for example for `glib` it cannot import `_glib`.

Comment: I'm just brainstorming here, but it sounds like you may want to consider either Appimage or Docker. With Appimage, you can create an application package with all dependencies included. With Docker, you can run an Ubuntu 18 container with all it's dependencies and the app you require.

Comment: maybe you could supply me with some Appimage tutorial for that purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really an expert on creating images for either of those - just pointing you in a direction. I'm pretty sure there's someone else here who knows way more that can help with that. :-)